How to enable vertical scroll bar on David Bacci's Deneb Gantt Chart?
I'm utilizing the beautiful Gantt chart created by David Bacci in Power BI. I have a long list of tasks and currently, scrolling with the mouse wheel zooms in/out the x-axis (time) instead of panning vertically.
I have tried editing the bottom "padding" from 0 to 100 as below, the scroll bar shows but when I use it data does not show (See screenshot), currently displayed data in the chart pan vertically and blanks appear instead of the remainder of the data.
"padding": {
"left": 5,
"right": 0,
"top": 5,
"bottom": 100
},
Scroll bar behaviour
Here's the link to the full spec:
https://github.com/PBI-David/Deneb-Showcase/blob/main/Gantt%20Chart/Gantt%202.0%20Spec.json
Thank you

I took the design decision to use the mouse wheel for zoom rather than scroll. You can drag and pan with the mouse to move the canvas vertically. If you definitely want a scrollbar, you can use the inbuilt Deneb one (you will lose the top of the gantt chart when you scroll it off page) or you can build a Vega one. Both are quite a bif of work and not really a stack overflow question but rather a few days of work for you or a consultant to develop for you.

Another option is group your tasks into phases and collapse all the phases so you don't have as far to pan

Thank you so much David for this beautiful tool. I went with the quick fix by setting a manual "height" value. As you said, this is at the expense of losing the top of the gantt chart when scrolling down.

I've asked Chat GPT Vicky Vega enter image description hereto add a scroll bar, it seems working. I can share the file updated.
https://github.com/LazaIrina/Gantt-by-Davide-Bacci-updated

The second link is broken, goes to a 404 Page not found
